# sed and passing a variable as search term for insert and append

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to specifically use insert before line and after line where pattern matches path.

All examples I have found so far only mention replace.
How do I correctly pass/read the variable for insert before and after line?

The example layout I am doing which obviously fails:

```bash
path="/home/pi/eqserver/source"
sed "/\$path/i <br>\n<span style="color:white">" ./input_file> ./output_file
```

Requested before and after: (the lines remain unchanged so before and after are the same)

```
<br>
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  In file included from /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/mac.cpp:112:0:
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/ss_define.h:151:0: warning: "DECODE_LENGTH_ATLEAST" redefined
<br>
<span style="color:white">
```

The span tag at the bottom is expected from a completely different and working pattern match. It was not a result of this pattern. I just included it as reference.

Every line that includes a path will have different content, but the path will always be the same.
I am turning all lines from a make output into a span of their own.
It is part of a browser friendly view of a build output.

Expected output per request:

```
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:white">
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  In file included from /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/mac.cpp:112:0:
 </span>
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:white">
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/ss_define.h:151:0: warning: "DECODE_LENGTH_ATLEAST" redefined
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:white">
```

The closing span would be added by a second sed with this solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of file content before and after?

Comment: Added that in the question.

Comment: You need to escape all the slashes in the path. Otherwise the first backslash ends the regular expression. Also, you shouldn't escape the `$`, that prevents the shell from expanding the variable.

Comment: `perl` or `awk` would probably make it easier to deal with a pattern that contains slashes.

Comment: Is this what's you're trying to do ? `TO_REPLACE=7; seq 10 | sed "s/$TO_REPLACE/BEFORE \0 AFTER/g"`. Also you may use another stop character, like '|', so sed "s|$TO_REPLACE|BEFORE \0 AFTER|g" to avoid clashing with the slashes in your path ? If not, we'll gladly take an "expected output" in your question because we don't get it.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to turn every line into a html <span>. No replaces, just inserts before and after. This example shown is the before.

Comment: @Bramar could you turn your first comment into an answer so I can accept it? I didn't really want to escape within the variable itself. But your suggestion did work. It was so simple and overlooked on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '\#/file/path#i above' -e '//a below' file
```

N.B. the alternative separator `\#...#` for the file path and two expressions (`-e`)to cater for the implicit newlines to end the `i` and `a` commands.

Comment: While both answers are great, I had to change accepted to this one, as it handles both before and after in one line, thereby reducing my script to nearly half. Also makes the script as a whole far easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're nearly there.

It looks like your #1 problem are the meta characters in $path.

```
$: path=$( echo "/home/pi/eqserver/source" | sed 's/\//\\\//g' )
$: sed "/$path/i <br>\n<span style=\"color:white\">" ./input_file 
<br>
<br>
<span style="color:white">
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  In file included from /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/mac.cpp:112:0:
<br>
<span style="color:white">
    Fri 17 Jun 2016 05:22:48 PM PDT:  /home/pi/eqserver/source/common/patches/ss_define.h:151:0: warning: "DECODE_LENGTH_ATLEAST" redefined
<br>
<span style="color:white">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am needing, it allows the flexibility to pass a static path from another part of the script in place of the quoted section without duplicating a path variable for 2 separate sections in the script due to escapes and such that would not play well elsewhere.